# Let x be a sequence such that the subseq. of even terms, and the subseq. of odd terms, both converges to $\ell$. Prove that $x \to \ell$ also.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

("subseq." is an abbreviation for subsequence) and $\underline{x} : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Am I supposed to use the choice functions for both sub-sequences,show they converge, then connect both facts in some way? Any guidance is appreciated !

Comment: I would use a $\delta$-$\epsilon$ argument.

Comment: or by contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Just work with the usual definition of the limit of a sequence. Let $\epsilon>0$ be given; you want to show that there is an $m(\epsilon)\in\Bbb N$ such that $|x_n-\ell|<\epsilon$ whenever $n\ge m(\epsilon)$. By hypothesis the subsequence of even-indexed terms converges to $\ell$, so there is an $m_{\text{even}}(\epsilon)\in\Bbb N$ such that $|x_{2n}-\ell|<\epsilon$ whenever $2n\ge m_\text{even}(\epsilon)$. Use this and the fact that the subsequence of odd-indexed terms also converges to $\ell$ to get the desired $m(\epsilon)$.